# Is there a way to use rhandsontable to show rows as columns and columns as rows?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rhandsontable

I am working on a Shiny app where I want to use rhandsontable to manage user input. There are a lot of columns and usually few rows. What I need is for the render to happen transposed: my columns as rows and my rows as columns:

My data:

|  | Field A | Field B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Case 1 | Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Case 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

How I wanted it to be represented:

|  | Case 1 | Case 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Field A | Cell 1 | Cell 3 |
| Field B | Cell 2 | Cell 4 |

Let me be clear: I want it to be represented this way, while I'd prefer the data frame containing the data to stay the same. Ideally rhandsontable's contextual menu and data verification functionalities would work the same, just for rows instead of columns.

I have tried forcing useTypes to be false, I have tried transposing my data frame and specifying rowHeaders, I don't know what else to try.

Comment: One solution would be to transpose the data before passing it to rhandsontable and then transpose it back when retrieving the data from the user with t(df). This approach may affect the performance of your app, especially if the data is large, as you'll be transposing the data twice every time the user edits it.

Comment: I had thought of this approach, but many functionalities are lost: I have several fields were I want to restrict user input to a few options through dropdowns, and I want to make sure certain fields are set to a certain type. When I transpose the data in that manner, I can't use these functionalities.